# Cannot run individual method tests

Tags: objective-c, swift, unit-testing, testing, interop

I have an Objective-C project I'm working on where I am integrating Swift. Right now I cannot run individual tests for the Objective-C tests that was possible before. If I check one of the diamond play buttons for an individual test it runs the tests for the whole class. Is there a way to fix this?

For the Swift tests that were integrated I used Quick & Nimble so I don't know if those libraries could have affected this.

Answer (score 1):

Hi [@Sahil Reddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13126090/sahil-reddy)

Your problem has likely to do with [Quick](https://github.com/Quick/Quick).

There is an [open PR](https://github.com/Quick/Quick/pull/936) that aims at solving this single test case selection behavior. From the PR description:

> When a non-Quick class is asked to selectively test e.g. `SomeClass/some_specific_function` the default behavior of using `QuickTestSuite` to generate the suites will cause it to execute every test function, rather than just the selected ones.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any workaround for this.

The only thing I came up with is to rewrite those tests to use Quick, and then use the focus prefixes (`fit`, `fcontext`, `fdescribe`) to run the examples or groups you are interested individually. That's a lot of extra work for a little gain, you might have to wait till the fix is merged and shipped, which I understand can be frustrating.